# Slightly refactored old Ruby example no longer produces all correct results

Tags: ruby

Currently working on a AWS c9 workspace and getting puzzling results:  Ruby version is 2.4.0

Using simple manual tdd, showing development of method.
Running final version of code and penultimate version of tests returns true for all tests:

```
HALF = 2

class NotAnIntegerError < ArgumentError ; end
class NegativePersonsError < ArgumentError ; end

def lines_of_communication(persons)
  begin
    raise NotAnIntegerError,  # check this  first!
      #Note: this test must be performed first, since comparing to 0 may fail
      'Expected argument must be scalar whole number' unless 
      persons.is_a?(Integer)  
    raise NegativePersonsError, 
      'Expected argument must be positive whole number' if persons <= 0  
    (persons * (persons - 1))/HALF
  rescue NotAnIntegerError, NegativePersonsError => exception
    #expressions enclosed in #{} are evaluated in double-quoted strings
    "#{exception.class}:  #{exception.message}"  
  end
end

#step13 => green again!

# Let's decide to only allow positive input => 
#   0 is no longer considered valid input
puts lines_of_communication(0) == 
  'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number'
puts lines_of_communication(-1) == 
  'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number'
puts lines_of_communication(1) == 0
# What if input not an integer?
puts lines_of_communication(0.5) == 
  'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number' # ETC.
```

However, running final version of code with final version of tests returns false when input is one:

```
#step14 => REFACTOR tests to be more efficient using hash

test_hash = 
{ 
  1 => 0, 2 => 1, 3 => 3, 4 => 6, 5 => 10, 10 => 45, 50 => 1225, 100 => 4950,  
  2 + 3 => 10, 10 - 5 => 10, 2 * 3 => 15, 12 / 2 => 15, 7 % 6 => 15,
  -1 => 'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number',
  0 => 'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number',
  0.5 => 'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number', 
  # ETC.
}
test_hash.each_pair {|people, value| puts lines_of_communication(people) == value}
```

The part I refactored was unrelated to the input that's failing.
Previously, this set of tests produced true for all inputs, and all the other tests (including the ones omitted here) produce true.
Debugging shows that when 1 is the argument, the value produced is 0 (so the test result should be true), and the type of the result is integer. 
Note that when running the previous set of tests, there was no problem with one as the input.

Comment: I don't know if this is causing your problem, but be aware that your hash contains several duplicate keys. Ruby will evaluate expressions like `2 + 3` and `10 - 5` to `5` and you will get a single key/value pair for those three keys. If you need to preserve those as separate keys, you'll need to make them strings and eval them in the test.

Comment: It fails not on `1 => 0` as an input as you might think, but on the `7 % 6 => 15`. It actually means `1 => 15` key-value pair, and it replaces `1 => 0` that you define first. So there are two issues with your test code: 1) duplicated keys inside a hash declaration (use array or string keys with interpolation instead) and (more important) falsely test case (I don't understand why do you expect 7 % 6 to as an input to produce 15 as an output)

Comment: THANKS moveson and Konstantin!
So focused on why first input was failing, didn't notice trainwreck on second line.
Had copied and pasted some other trivial examples there, meaning to  edit for context  -- and forgot all about it.
Thanks for making me look in the right place, although still puzzled why it APPEARED to fail on first input instead of mishmash on second line.
New, EDITED line reads: `3 + 3 => 15, 10 - 3 => 21, 2 * 4 => 28, 18 / 2 => 36, 24 % 13 => 55,` no longer appears to fail on first input, all results true.

Comment: OK, since bad example key replaced good example key, it becomes obvious why failure occurred where it did.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by moveson and Konstantin, error was in unedited second line, not first input.  Clearing up carelessly entered examples gave good results:

```
test_hash = 
{ 
  1 => 0, 2 => 1, 3 => 3, 4 => 6, 5 => 10, 10 => 45, 50 => 1225, 100 => 4950,  
  3 + 3 => 15, 10 - 3 => 21, 2 * 4 => 28, 18 / 2 => 36, 24 % 13 => 55,
  -1 => 'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number',
  0 => 'NegativePersonsError:  Expected argument must be positive whole number',
  0.5 => 'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number', 
  'cat' => 'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number', 
  :+ => 'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number', 
  [1, 2] => 'NotAnIntegerError:  Expected argument must be scalar whole number',
  {:dog=>'cat'} => "NotAnIntegerError:  " + 
                 "Expected argument must be scalar whole number"
}

test_hash.each_pair {|people, value| puts lines_of_communication(people) == value}
```